# Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I am building a small Android app with Kotlin and Android Studio. Everything worked fine, but out of the blue (at least what seems to me), I am stuck  with

```
Error:Execution failed for task :bahndb:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: 
Error while merging dex archives: 
C:\Users\Dieter\AndroidStudioProjects\zuegliwidget\bahndb\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\13.jar,
```

and so on until 47.jar when I try to run an Instrumented Test. Local tests all work ok. It is strange that even earlier checkout that had worked before show this behaviour (some update? I have reinstalled Android Studio twice)

I have read all message on the subject here, none helped:

- Use clean build (I do every time)
- Invalidate cache (over and over)
- added multiDex
- Tried different Kotlin plugins
- Uninstalled 3.1 Canary 5, installed stable, reinstalled canary 5
- Un/commented dependencies one after the other (this had worked earlier)
  Running Lint, but failed with error

App has 2 submodules, bahndb and http. Here are the gradle files, if it matters

https://github.com/dmenne/zuegliwidget/blob/master/build.gradle

https://github.com/dmenne/zuegliwidget/blob/master/app/build.gradle

https://github.com/dmenne/zuegliwidget/blob/master/bahndb/build.gradle << Most likely guilty

https://github.com/dmenne/zuegliwidget/blob/master/http/build.gradle

Is there a systematic approach to locate the source of the problem

Comment: Look at the Gradle Console's full output and see if there is a Java stack trace with details about what went wrong. There should be one.

Comment: Thanks. Found: Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory. This must be a transitive inclusion, and I have not been able to figure out the syntax to exclude it.

Comment: Well, [that class is part of the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.html). Some third-party library that you are using is not designed for Android and baked in a copy of that class or is pulling in that class via a dependency. My guess would be `org.simpleframework:simple-xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @CommonsWare's comments, I found that I had

```
implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'){
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

in one submodule, but had forgotten the exclude-part in the other.